# Does Vuetify have an equivalent to Quasar's QSplitter component?

Tags: vuetify.js, quasar-framework, vuetifyjs3

I've been asked to switch a Quasar project to Vuetify, and one of the components I'm trying to find an equivalent for is [Quasar's QSplitter component](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/splitter), specifically to create a vertically-oriented draggable divider.  Does Vuetify have an equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is "No", but I was able to find a substitute in the third-party package [splitpanes](https://antoniandre.github.io/splitpanes/).